# force wsimport (Java 10/11) to tolerate TLSv1 and weak cipher

Tags: security, wsimport, java-10, tls1.0, java-11

I use `wsimport` to generate code from a particular `WSDL`. I tried Java 10, it failed handshake, then I tried Java 9 and it was okay.

I watched communication using `wireshark`, and the cause became clear, the server I communicated still uses TLSv1, and I guess Java 10 `wsimport` no longer tolerate that (not by default at least), although 9 does.

There is nothing I can do with the server, so the question becomes how I can run Java 10 wsimport with TLSv1 tolerance?

Comment: 1. Mostly, [with Java11 there would be no support for `wsimport`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320). 2. This [bug seems to be related to your issue?](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8190917)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More investigation was done, and the most helpful test was done using [ssl labs](http://www.ssllabs.com). It turned out that the server supports a weak cipher suite: `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`.

The issue was solved by adding the following java option:

```
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

Cannot specify the cipher suite as `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`. Java's naming convention requires it to be called `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`.

Side note: the bug mentioned in @nullpointer's comment above was solved in all three versions I tried: Java 9/10/11.